# HTML5 websocket-support for NGINX

Tags: php, plugins, nginx, html5

I need websockets in a project for HTML5 and PHP, but it don´t works.
I read something about that NGINX is not supporting them.

Is there a possibility to install a plugin that brings me the support for that?

greetings

Comment: I think it would be a better idea to ask this on serverfault.com or superuser.com as you would probably find better/faster answers there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HTML5 websockets with the latest stable Nginx installed, to easily install it use the repositories:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Remember, you have to remove your old `nginx`, `nginx-common` and `nginx-full` packages before installing the new version.

I've already tested proxying websockets ( using socket.io ) on Nginx 1.4.1 and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there are any nginx modules that add support for websockets.  However the nginx [roadmap](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/roadmap) indicates that version 1.3 will have support for them.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand there are a number of pieces involved beyond just the web server (nginx), but "support for proxying of WebSocket connections" in nginx was released in v1.4.0.

**More Info:**

http://nginx.org/

http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not that difficult. You can find more information [here](http://blog.i-evaluation.com/2012/12/09/installing-nginx-with-websockets-support/). Posted that couple days ago.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.